# I've unintentionally created a production database. Will this destroy the production data that already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, rspec, production-environment

Context:
I've built a rails app that's in production. Originally, the scope of the project was small so I didn't need to write tests, but as it grows, it's now imperative that I have them.

As I set up rspec along with the test database, I ran the following command:

```
`rake db:create:all`
```

I received the following response:

```
Database 'db/development.sqlite3' already exists
Database 'db/test.sqlite3' already exists
Created database 'db/production.sqlite3'`
```

Question:
Given the fact that I have a deployed application (on Heroku) with a production database that's already up and running, is that final line (
`Created database 'db/production.sqlite3`) going to destroy any data once I merge my changes and push my code up to production?

Further, since I'm already using a different database in production, should I delete it? If so, how?

I would be happy to add any details that someone would need in order to give a helpful response! Thanks in advance

Comment: You have run that command locally? Right? 
First of all, all the db files are usually added in .gitignore file unless you have manually removed them. So, merging and pushing your changes will never affect the .sqlite3 files as they will be ignored by git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses Postgres, not sqlite last time I checked.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Look at what's in the `production` section of your gemfile and it should be postgres.  In test/development you can use sqlite.

Any changes you made on your machine with `rake db:create` should also be local.  If you make sure to configure your database.yml properly (also in the link above) you shouldn't have to worry about messing up your database on heroku.

Would not hurt to create a backup of your production data if you can though.